# SQL update a column from other tables based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-server

There are three tables: core, system, and fact:

1. core table contains following columns core_date, close_date, x, y, z, ata and  soln_imp column
2. system table contains the following columns system_date,x,y and z column
3. fact table contains the fact_date column

I want to update core_date(feed this column) column of core table based on the following conditions,

when ata column of core table start with 10 then select fact_date column of fact table

else
select system date from system table based on below matching columns like
x,y,z column of core should be equal to x,y,z column of system

In any case, if soln_imp column of core table is null, then select close_date of core table

Could you please make a query for the requirement above?

I have created the query below:

```
update DB set 
     core_date = 


  case 
       when ata like '10%'

       THEN  (select distinct fact_date  from FACT)

  else     
   case when soln_imp is null
                   then close_date 

              else

                   (select distinct  system_date
                    from Core c left join Systems s on 
                            c.x = s.x
                            and  c.y = s.y and c.z = s.z
                            where c.soln_imp is not null) 

              end 
   end
```

After running the query, I'm getting this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows `=, !=, <, <= , >, >=` or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Could you please suggest me the correct script if mine is wrong?

Comment: Maybe a MIN or MAX aggregation instead of the distinct may help, together with an appropriate GROUP BY. Just to be sure, there is only one value returned by the selects. So test your selects first, before putting them together. Apart from that it is quite hard to help without sample data for your tables.

Comment: mysql and sql-server differs. Please choose only one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your query and i could make the update. It seems that can be the data, I reproduce your querys, your tables but not your data. The error is saying that this select:

```
select distinct  system_date
                from Core c left join Systems s on 
                        c.x = s.x
                        and  c.y = s.y and c.z = s.z
                        where c.soln_imp is not null
```

Is giving more than one row. First thing i would say for you to do is to put the alias in system_date, so s.system_date. Then i would run this query until it gets one row with your needs.

I can help you more but u have to give me some sample of your data.